# Exception: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. on speech recognizer object in UWP App

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I keep getting this exception on ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync method: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." even when the SpeechRecognizer object is in "Idle" state. Below is the code snippet

```
    if (SpeechRecognizer.State == SpeechRecognizerState.Idle)
    {
            await SpeechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
    }
```

Here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/enable-continuous-dictation mentioned that speech recognizer must be in "Idle" state in order to call StartAsync(). What is wrong here?

Comment: The code you've posted is definitely right. It's hard to reproduce your issue only with these code. Could you please share a [mcve]? Besides, have you tried with the official [Speech recognition and synthesis sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis)? Does it have the same problem?

Comment: I dont think other parts of code would have to do anything with this. This is all the code that I have on the click of a button. I have a simple button on the click of which I want to call StartAsync() so as to start continuous speech recognition. I checked the other sample that you shared as well and there I find the same code.

Comment: I get this exception when I have mixed debugging (managed and native on). The sample code does not have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you got this exception when you tried to call `StartAsync` method, but the problem may be not here. As you've seen, in the official sample, it also use this code and it works well.

As I don't have the other parts of your code, it hard to say what caused this exception. I'd suggest you follow the steps in [**Continuous dictation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/enable-continuous-dictation) and refer to the [Speech recognition and synthesis sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis) to implement your own.

Some key points here are:

> - Fetch the dispatcher for the UI thread if you update the UI of your app in the continuous recognition event handlers.
> - Initialize the speech recognizer.
> - Compile the built-in dictation grammar. **Note** Speech recognition requires at least one constraint to define a recognizable vocabulary. If no constraint is specified, a predefined dictation grammar is used. See [Speech recognition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/speech-recognition).
> - Set up the event listeners for recognition events.

And one possible reason that can cause your problem is missing compiling constraints in initialization. We need to call [SpeechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn653240) before we start speech recognize.

Ref document:

> **CompileConstraintsAsync** must always be called before [RecognizeAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognizer.recognizeasync) or [RecognizeWithUIAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognizer.recognizewithuiasync), even if no constraints are specified in the [Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognizer.constraints) property.

If we missed `await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();` in initialization, we will get `Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.` exception when starting a recognition session.

Comment: I called CompileConstraintAsyc() in the Page_Loading event so I didn't call it in this click event. Calling it again here solved the problem. Thank you so much Jay :)